How do I support url masks with and without tags?
I'm using URL masks. I want to support two possible URL paths:

https://myapp.com/myservice/_mytag/* - go directly to tagged revision
https://myapp.com/myservice/* - behave as though my url mask was just /<service>

I want to use "_" to distinguish between api methods and tags/versions. My URL map is not working though.
I have 2 backend services, one for just <service> and one for <service>/<tag>
### service and tag
resource "google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group" "service_and_tag" {
  name                  = "service-and-tag"
  network_endpoint_type = "SERVERLESS"
  region                = var.region
  cloud_run {
    url_mask = "/<service>/<tag>"
  }
}
resource "google_compute_backend_service" "service_and_tag" {
  name                  = "service-and-tag"
  protocol              = "HTTPS"
  load_balancing_scheme = "EXTERNAL_MANAGED"
  backend {
    group           = google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group.service_and_tag.id
    balancing_mode  = "UTILIZATION"
    capacity_scaler = 1.0
  }
}

### service only
resource "google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group" "service" {
  name                  = "service-and-tag"
  network_endpoint_type = "SERVERLESS"
  region                = var.region
  cloud_run {
    url_mask = "/<service>/<tag>"
  }
}
resource "google_compute_backend_service" "service" {
  name                  = "service-and-tag"
  protocol              = "HTTPS"
  load_balancing_scheme = "EXTERNAL_MANAGED"
  backend {
    group           = google_compute_region_network_endpoint_group.service.id
    balancing_mode  = "UTILIZATION"
    capacity_scaler = 1.0
  }
}

I'm trying to route to them with this URL map but its not working:
resource "google_compute_url_map" "cloud_run" {
  name            = "cloud-run"

  # Default to just the service
  default_service = google_compute_backend_service.service.id

  path_matcher {
    name            = split(".", google_dns_record_set.my_app.name)[0]

    # Default to just the service
    default_service = google_compute_backend_service.service.self_link

    path_rule {
      # If "_" included in second position route to service_and_tag backend
      paths   = ["/{app_name=*}/_{tag_and_methods=**}"]

      service = google_compute_backend_service.service_and_tag.self_link
      route_action {
        url_rewrite {
          path_prefix_rewrite = "/{app_name}/{tag_and_methods}"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

It always routes to google_compute_backend_service.service even if I try to go to path: https://myapp.com/myservice/_mytag01.
Why isn't my URL map matching the url?
